# Remove Suffix at the end in SQL Server (MISS, DR)

Tags: sql, sql-server

So my data currently has a suffix in the first name of a customer. it could be: MISS|MRS|MISS|MR|DR|MS|JT|CHD|CHLD|DEAN|REV|MRI|EARL|DRI|DEAN|MSI.

I am trying to get rid of the suffix that comes at the end.

Here is an example of the data

> First Name:
>
> RUTH ANNE MRS
>
> CHRISTOPHER MR

Here is the code I wrote but my code only removes one letter so Ruth Anne MRS would appear as RUTH ANNE MR

```
 REPLACE(SUBSTRING(First_Name, CHARINDEX('MISS|MRS|MISS|MR|DR|MS|JT|CHD|CHLD|DEAN|REV|MRI|EARL|DRI|DEAN|MSI', First_Name), LEN(First_Name)), 'MISS|MRS|MISS|MR|DR|MS|JT|CHD|CHLD|DEAN|REV|MRI|EARL|DRI|DEAN|MSI', '   ')
```

Comment: You need to write replace for particular suffix. eg Replace(Replace(Replace(First_Name,'MISS',''),'MRS',''),'MR','') like that

Comment: Do ALL first names include that suffix in your data and is that format consistent across ALL records?

Comment: @user2042214 Doing a REPLACE is a terrible idea.   What if somebody's first name is "Missy"?

Answer (score 0):

Write SQL that:

Gets the CHARINDEX of the first space character in the REVERSE string,

Checks to see whether that substring fits one of the suffix patterns,

And if so, returns the original string shortened (using LEFT) by the length of that substring.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the below query to remove the suffix at the end

```
DECLARE @string VARCHAR(4000);
```

SET     @string = SPACE(1) + 'RUTH ANNE MRS';

WITH    ToRemove (word)
AS      (
        SELECT  'MISS' COLLATE SQL_LATIN1_GENERAL_CP1_CI_AS UNION ALL
        SELECT  'MRS' COLLATE SQL_LATIN1_GENERAL_CP1_CI_AS UNION ALL
        SELECT  'MISS' COLLATE SQL_LATIN1_GENERAL_CP1_CI_AS UNION ALL
        SELECT  'MR' COLLATE SQL_LATIN1_GENERAL_CP1_CI_AS UNION ALL
        SELECT  'DR' COLLATE SQL_LATIN1_GENERAL_CP1_CI_AS UNION ALL
        SELECT  'MS' COLLATE SQL_LATIN1_GENERAL_CP1_CI_AS UNION ALL
        SELECT  'JT' COLLATE SQL_LATIN1_GENERAL_CP1_CI_AS UNION ALL
        SELECT  'CHD' COLLATE SQL_LATIN1_GENERAL_CP1_CI_AS UNION ALL
        SELECT  'CHLD' COLLATE SQL_LATIN1_GENERAL_CP1_CI_AS UNION ALL
        SELECT  'DEAN' COLLATE SQL_LATIN1_GENERAL_CP1_CI_AS UNION ALL
        SELECT  'REV' COLLATE SQL_LATIN1_GENERAL_CP1_CI_AS UNION ALL
        SELECT  'MRI' COLLATE SQL_LATIN1_GENERAL_CP1_CI_AS UNION ALL
        SELECT  'EARL' COLLATE SQL_LATIN1_GENERAL_CP1_CI_AS UNION ALL
        SELECT  'DRI' COLLATE SQL_LATIN1_GENERAL_CP1_CI_AS UNION ALL
        SELECT  'DEAN' COLLATE SQL_LATIN1_GENERAL_CP1_CI_AS UNION ALL
        SELECT  'MSI' COLLATE SQL_LATIN1_GENERAL_CP1_CI_AS 
        )
SELECT  @string = 
            REPLACE
                (
                @string COLLATE SQL_LATIN1_GENERAL_CP1_CI_AS,
                ToRemove.word COLLATE SQL_LATIN1_GENERAL_CP1_CI_AS,
                SPACE(1) COLLATE SQL_LATIN1_GENERAL_CP1_CI_AS
                )
FROM    ToRemove
WHERE   CHARINDEX
            (
            ToRemove.word COLLATE SQL_LATIN1_GENERAL_CP1_CI_AS, 
            @string COLLATE SQL_LATIN1_GENERAL_CP1_CI_AS
            ) > 0;

SELECT  @string;

Comment: I would question using replace in this situation.  What if the name was "Dean Mr" or "Earl Dr" or "Missy Miss"  or "Drake Mr"? You wouldn't end up with the expected result.  Sure, for the sample data provided, but I'm sure there's a larger content of data in play here.

Answer (score 0):

If you store the titles to the table, you may do it with a single SELECT

Prepare test data

```
CREATE TABLE #titles (title nvarchar(10));
INSERT INTO #titles (title) VALUES ('M.'), ('Mme'), ('Mlle');
CREATE TABLE #data (fullname nvarchar(100));
INSERT INTO #data (fullname) VALUES
('John Doe M.'),
('Mary Jones Mme'),
('Doctor Who Mme'),
('Leia Organa Mlle')
```

Querying

```
SELECT 
    d.fullname, 
    SUBSTRING(d.fullname, 1, LEN(d.fullname) - LEN(t.title)) AS new_fullname,
    SUBSTRING(d.fullname, LEN(d.fullname) - LEN(t.title) + 1, LEN(t.title)) AS found_title
FROM #data d LEFT JOIN #titles t ON d.fullname LIKE '%' + t.title
```

Result

```
fullname                       new_fullname                   found_title
------------------------------ ------------------------------ ------------------------------
John Doe M.                    John Doe                       M.
Mary Jones Mme                 Mary Jones                     Mme
Doctor Who Mme                 Doctor Who                     Mme
Leia Organa Mlle               Leia Organa                    Mlle
```